# Interesting Locus problem

Tags: coordinate-systems

A variable line passes through $P(2,-1)$ and cuts the co-ordinate axes at $A$ and $B$ respectively.

$Q$ lies on line AB such that $$\frac{2}{PQ} = \frac{1}{PA} + \frac{1}{PB}$$ Find the locus of point Q

Comment: @ Lucas. Without loss of generality, you can shift $P$ to origin and call it a harmonic mean locus for $Q$. Its locus is available. If you agree I could edit it. But at first please put down how you started  solving it.

Comment: @Narasimham What will happen to PA and PB when P becomes origin?

Comment: I meant to shift the entire diagram so that P is center of origin  in finding inversion circles.

Comment: @Lucas 1) Is length of PQ ( harmonic average ) always the same? 2) How sure are you that that the locus exists and is unique? 3) Should the locus pass through the given fixed points A and B ? 4) Is it not a repeat question?

Answer (score 0):

$Q$ lies on a line through the origin with slope $\frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

Let we prove it through the properties of the circular inversion. We take a circle with centre at $P$ and radius $1$, then consider the inverse of the $x$-axis and the inverse of the $y$-axis. They are two circles ($\Gamma_x,\Gamma_y$) meeting at $P$. We have $A^{-1}\in\Gamma_x$ and $B^{-1}\in\Gamma_y$: in order to get $Q$, we just need the inverse of the midpoint of $A^{-1}B^{-1}$. But the midpoint of $A^{-1}B^{-1}$ always lies on a particular circle (the red circle in the above picture) of the coaxal bundle given by $\Gamma_x$ and $\Gamma_y$, i.e. the circle through $P$, the centre of $\Gamma_x$ and the centre of $\Gamma_y$. It follows that $Q$ always lies on a particular line, the line through $(2,1)$ and $(-2,-1)$.

That is also a consequence of the fact that the initial condition grants that the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) $(P,A,Q,B)$ is always the same. A third alternative is provided by the following fact: in a trapezoid having bases with lengths $a,b$, the segment parallel to the bases through the point of intersection of the diagonals has length given by the harmonic mean of $a$ and $b$, i.e. $\frac{2ab}{a+b}$.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a *related case* where P is the origin ( without loss of generality, the entire graph can be shifted to required point) with harmonic mean of two free  segments (shown as dots $A,B$ , intersection points with radius vector) as constant (represented by the unit purple circle shown).

[image: HarmonicMeanConstant]